# Issues with test alignment only on small screens like mobile

Tags: html, css

So I have a problem that only happens on the mobile version of my site which is written in a responsive manner. When I write a sentence it looks great on a large screen but when small it doesn't look how I want it. Example:

## 1 Should be: (GOOD)

```
Earn points for doing everyday things, like posting, sharing, 
liking or just being active!
Then jump to our rewards store & select an instant gift card.
```

## 2 Currently: (Bad)

```
Earn points for doing everyday things, like posting, sharing,
```

liking or just being active!
    Then jump to our rewards store & select an instant gift card.

How do I get the sentence to all be in line with each other like in example #1 Iv checked and none of the solutions on the site worked for me. This is my first post so I apologize if it's not properly complete. I will improve it!

Tried using this code didn't work.

```
@media all and (max-width: 360px){
.mleft20{
    margin-left: 20px;
 }
 }
```

Non working Image
[image]

Working Image
[image]

Code used:

```
<br>
<h3><?php echo $this->translate('Be Rewarded!'); ?></h3>
<BR>
<head>
<style>
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
display: flex;
}

.column {
width: 33.33%;
padding: 5px;
max-width: 200px;
display: block;
margin: 15px auto;
}


/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other 
instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.column {
width: 100%;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>&nbsp &nbsp Earn points for doing everyday things, like posting, sharing, 
liking or just being active!</p>
<p>&nbsp &nbsp Then jump to our rewards store & select an instant gift card. 
</p>



<div class="row">
<div class="column">
<img src="http://zoeaa.com/public/admin/starbucksoffer.png" alt="Snow" 
style="width:100%">
</div>
<div class="column">
<img src="http://zoeaa.com/public/admin/mysteryoffers.jpg" alt="Forest" 
style="width:100%">
</div>
<div class="column">
<img src="http://zoeaa.com/public/admin/targetoffers.png" alt="Mountains" 
style="width:100%">
</div>
<div class="column">
<img src="http://zoeaa.com/public/admin/starbucksoffer.png" alt="Snow" 
style="width:100%">
</div>
<div class="column">
<img src="http://zoeaa.com/public/admin/mysteryoffers.jpg" alt="Forest" 
style="width:100%">
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
<br>
<h3><?php echo $this->translate('Get your invite!'); ?></h3>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Remove &nbsp &nbsp in both paragraphs and add CSS: **padding-left: 2rem**

Comment: @Gerard Explain a little further, would this be in line CSS? Could you give an example?

Comment: I have added an example of what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  padding-left: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<p>Earn points for doing everyday things, like posting, sharing, liking or just being active!</p>
<p>Then jump to our rewards store &amp; select an instant gift card.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi when you to align div center @ mobile(not only in mobile you can use wherever you want) use margin:0px auto; with some width:90%;...if still its doesn't work lets me know